# Running runas cmd in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, runas

I am a beginner and am trying to understand how to use the runas command in Windows Powershell.

When I type the following command into Powershell:

```
runas /user:<localmachinename>\administrator cmd
```

I am asked to enter a password. When I do so, I am told that:

```
1326: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

Also, when I type this command into Powershell:

```
runas /user:AdministratorAccountName@ ComputerName
```

I get:

```
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to acquire user password
```

I can't see the password when I type it in. But I have done it multiple times correctly and always get those messages.

Would appreciate some help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `runas /user:$($env:COMPUTERNAME)\Administrator cmd`?

Comment: or `/user:.\Administrator`. Scratch that - just tested it, Mathias' suggestion works, mine doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
runas /user:administrator cmd
```

without the backslash before `administrator`. That works for me – when I replace `administrator` with a valid user name for an administrator on my computer, of course.

When it comes to the other command you tried:

```
runas /user:AdministratorAccountName@ ComputerName
```

it should read

```
runas /user:ComputerName\AdministratorAccountName
```

where `ComputerName` is a valid computer name and `AdministratorAccountName` is a valid name of a user account.