# batch command to run program as administrator (always)

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, jenkins, build

I am trying to run windows program (atmelstudio) as administrator through batch command in Jenkins build process. So far I have enabled original .exec and all shortcuts to run as administrator through Windows GUI. But when I run windows BATCH command `START /WAIT atmelstudio example.cproj /build release /out build.log` it doesn't always run as administrator. When I restart windows build machine and then run this program through jenkins build, it runs as administrator, but in scheduled nightly build it always fail to runs as administrator.

I have tried

`runas /user:admin-user@host-name /WAIT atmelstudio example.cproj /build release /out build.log`

`runas /user:host-name\admin-user /WAIT atmelstudio example.cproj /build release /out build.log`

but this didn't help at all.

what I have to do here to make atmelstudio to run as administrator always through batch command ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running runas cmd in Powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/859242/running-runas-cmd-in-powershell)