# Is there an equivalent "sudo" command in PowerShell on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, powershell

I would like to try and use PowerShell as my default shell on Ubuntu 18.04, however with bash I can opt to run some commands as `sudo` and I'm not sure how I'd be able to do that with PowerShell as it doesn't have `sudo` as a concept.

In PowerShell on Windows you have to run the shell as an administrator. If I set my default shell to PowerShell I worry that I wouldn't be able to run the commands I might need to without sudo, would I have to drop into bash? I don't want to run the default shell as an administrator by default.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/859242/running-runas-cmd-in-powershell but not sure if `runas` will work on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to use PowerShell in Ubuntu but you will need the sudo command. You can do `bash -c "sudo <bash command>"`. `sudo` usually doesn't work in PowerShell because it is a Unix Executable so you will need to use sudo with a Bash command. As pointed out by others, `runas` is your best option in PowerShell. Note that you will need Ubuntu installed or some other method of accessing Bash in CMD/PowerShell. I think you already have the Ubuntu command line installed using WSL so you should be fine if that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

There is no sudo in PowerShell natively. That is what -RunAs is for, but generally not the same thing either.

There are modules that are wrappers that try to emulate it. Yet, not the same thing. These have been around before PSCore (PowerShellv6/7 existed), so no guarantee that they will work in those versions.

```
Find-Module -Name '*sudo*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
<#
# Results

Version Name   Repository Description                                                                            
------- ----   ---------- -----------                                                                            
2.1.0   Sudo   PSGallery  Use functionality similar to sudo in PowerShell. GitHub: https://github.com/pldmgg/Sudo
1.4.0   PSSudo PSGallery  Function for executing programs with adminstrative privileges  
#>
```