# Login as admin into powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, windows-11

Is there a way to get admin permissions in PowerShell while being logged in to the terminal?
Linux has "sudo" or "login as root" to get those priviledges but I couldn't find anything similar in Windows yet.
Having something like that would really benefit my workflow!

*EDIT:* I am running Windows 11 Pro 21H2
Build 22000.613.co_release.210604-1628

Comment: I don't think there is: https://superuser.com/questions/1554758/is-there-an-equivalent-sudo-command-in-powershell-on-ubuntu

Comment: What the exact **Windows version** you wish to run the terminal with administrative privileges? Add to your post and its tags too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start the new elevated process using the
[Start-Process command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process?view=powershell-7.2)
with the `RunAs` verb.

Example:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "notepad" -Verb RunAs
```

Comment: From what I've seen before, that's the closest it can get to a "sudo"!
I'm gonna wait for one or two days, if anyone is gonna post a better way on how to do this and if not, I'm going to accept this as the best answer.
Thanks ^^

Comment: What would I have to do, to start for example "pip3 [options]" as an elevated process? Does that even work?

Answer (score 1):

To run the **command prompt** with administrative privileges:

```
runas /user:administrator C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

To run the **Powershell** with administrative privileges:

```
runas /user:administrator C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

I ran the command lines above on **Windows 10 Enterprise Edition**.

References:

[Runas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11))